# How to keep object properties default values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to know how do keep initialed values of object properties

```
class MyClass{
  constructor(){
     this.settings = {
         theme: 'dark',
         confirmBtn: 'ok',
         cancelBtn: 'cancel',
     }
  }
}

let obj= new MyClass();
obj.settings = {
  theme: 'white' 
}
```

and other properties like confirmBtn keep their values that assigned in the class declaration.

Comment: `constractor`? You mean `constructor`, right?

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options.

1. Only assign to the one property:

   ```js
   obj.settings.theme = "white";
   ```
2. Use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) if you have an object of properties you want to assign (here I have just the one property, but you could have more):

   ```js
   Object.assign(obj.settings, {
       theme: "white",
   });
   ```

   `Object.assign` copies all of the own, enumerable properties from the objects provided as the second argument onward into the object provided as the first argument.
3. Use object spread syntax `...` on both the existing `obj.settings` object and the new settings object into an anonymous, new object and assign that to `obj.settings`:

   ```
   obj.settings = { ...obj.settings, ...{ theme: "white" } };
   ```

   Though there's no reason to do that here, just update the settings object you have. This option can be very useful in situations where you want to avoid ever modifying the existing object (state updates in various MVC libs, etc.).

---

In a self-answer it appears you wanted to move the assignment *into* the constructor, which you didn't mention in the question. I'd handle that by using parameter destructuring combined with destructuring default values and a parameter default (just a blank object):

```
class MyClass {
    constructor({theme = "dark", confirmBtn = "ok", cancelBtn = "cancel"} = {}) {
        this.settings = {
            theme,
            confirmBtn,
            cancelBtn,
        };
    }
}

let obj= new MyClass({
    theme: "white",
});
```

Live Example:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor({theme = "dark", confirmBtn = "ok", cancelBtn = "cancel"} = {}) {
        this.settings = {
            theme,
            confirmBtn,
            cancelBtn,
        };
    }
}

// Settings not specified get defaulted
const obj1 = new MyClass({
    theme: "white",
});
console.log(obj1.settings);

// No parameter at all gets all defaults
const obj2 = new MyClass();
console.log(obj2.settings);
```

You can also do it with `Object.assign`, though I like the expressiveness of the defaults all being in the constructor signature:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(settings = {}) {
        this.settings = Object.assign(
            {},
            {
                theme: "dark",
                confirmBtn: "ok",
                cancelBtn: "cancel",
            },
            settings
        );
    }
}

let obj= new MyClass({
    theme: "white",
});
```

Live Example:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(settings = {}) {
        this.settings = Object.assign(
            {},
            {
                theme: "dark",
                confirmBtn: "ok",
                cancelBtn: "cancel",
            },
            settings
        );
    }
}

// Settings not specified get defaulted
const obj1 = new MyClass({
    theme: "white",
});
console.log(obj1.settings);

// No parameter at all gets all defaults
const obj2 = new MyClass();
console.log(obj2.settings);
```

Comment: I posted an answer to my question @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @Hamidj - I've updated my answer to show what I'd do instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the private class feature and use getters and setters.

```js
class MyClass{
    #settings;

    constractor(){
        this.#settings={
             theme:'dark',
             confirmBtn:'ok',
             cancelBtn:'cancel'
        }
    }

    getSettings(){
        return this.#settings;
    }

}
```

trying to access `#setting` swill yield an error

Comment: Why not use a Javascript getter then? `get settings() { return this.#settings; }`. What you wrote is what getters look like in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved  my issue by JQuery $.extend:
I defined a deafult object and get options as another object and merged them.

```
class MyClass{
  constructor(options){
     this.default = {
       theme: 'dark',
       confirmBtn: 'ok',
       cancelBtn: 'cancel',
      }
      this.settings=$.extend({},this.default,options);
  }
}
let obj= new MyClass({
    theme:'dark
 });
```

Comment: `$.extend` is just jQuery's predecessor of `Object.assign`. I wouldn't use it in new code, I'd use the standard function instead. Separately, you didn't say you wanted to move the assignment into the constructor, or I'd've shown you how to do that.